# Is it possible to execute some part of makefile with sudo, some part without sudo?

Tags: linux, makefile

Say, for example,  I have a makefile:

```
front:
    cd front && (sudo make -f Makefile.linux )   -- require sudo

back: 
    cd back && (make -f Makefile.linux )

clean:
    cd front && (make -f Makefile.linux clean)
    cd back  && (make -f Makefile.linux clean)
```

Is it possible to do it? If yes, what is the right way to do it? Thanks

LJ

Comment: Generally you should always use `$(MAKE)`, not `make`, when invoking make recursively.

Answer (score 2):

[Sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) is just a program that allows you to authenticate and then run programs as root.  After you authenticate, you are allowed to freely run commands as root through sudo, without having to re-authenticate for a configurable period of time.  Any commands that you don't prefix with `sudo` will just be run with your regular user's privileges.

If you are expecting this makefile to be used on the command line then this is the correct way to do it.  On the other hand, if you want the makefile to be used in a graphical environment, then you may want to use `gksu` or `gksudo` depending on what distribution you're using.

Comment: Tried it and it is not working. Unlike further sudo calls on the command line the sudo inside the makefile does not know that the user has already authenticated in the session.

Comment: @BeniBela - probably because each command in the makefile is run in a separate shell, and `sudo` only sets up the timestamp (authority to run `sudo` without a password prompt) for the current shell, so it is "lost" for the next command. Same thing happens if you open up a few tabs in terminal and `sudo` in one of them: if you switch to another tab and `sudo` you again have to enter your password since it's a different shell.